# K8s hpa multiple metrics

Tags: kubernetes, metrics, scaling, hpa

I use metrics and custom metrics for my app in k8s.
I scrape my custom metrics via prometheus-adapter.
And while I'm deploying my custom metrics and new hpa parameters I see strange hpa behavior.
For example. My app already apply new hpa parameters and now scaling with CPU and custom node_js metrics.
And I see next situation

```
kubectl get hpa -n my-app
NAME               REFERENCE           TARGETS                    MINPODS   MAXPODS   REPLICAS   AGE
autoscaler-my-ap   Deployment/my-app   69%/100%, <unknown>/100m   1         4         4          1d
```

CPU is not in 100% and seconds metrics is unknown. But I have max replicas in my cluster.

When I delete in hpa custom metrics or deploy prometheus-adapter with new custom metrics my app scale down to 1 replicas.
I can't find any information about this behavior can you please explain me why this happen?